# Installing strapi project on windows, incompatible module

Tags: windows, dependencies, strapi

λ **npx create-strapi-app strap-test --quickstart**

Creating a new Strapi application at C:\Users\Jell\strap-test.

Creating a quickstart project.
Creating files.

Error while installing dependencies:

- warning strapi > **boom@7.3.0**: This module has moved and is now available at @hapi/boom.
  Please update your dependencies as this version is no longer maintained an may contain bugs and security issues.
- warning strapi > boom > **hoek@6.1.3**: This module has moved and is now available at @hapi/hoek. Please update your dependencies as this version is no longer maintained an may contain bugs and security issues.
- warning strapi-admin > **postcss-smart-import@0.7.6**: This project is not maintained anymore. Please use postcss-import instead.
- warning strapi-admin > react-intl > **intl-relativeformat@2.2.0:** This package has been deprecated, please see migration guide at 'https://github.com/formatjs/formatjs/tree/master/packages/intl-relativeformat#migration-guide'
- warning strapi-admin > react-datetime > create-react-class > fbjs > **core-js@1.2.7:** core-js@<2.6.8 is no longer maintained. Please, upgrade to core-js@3 or at least to actual version of core-js@2.
- warning strapi-admin > precss > postcss-preset-env > postcss-color-functional-notation > postcss-values-parser > flatten@1.0.2: I wrote this module a very long time ago; you should use something else.
- warning strapi-plugin-users-permissions > purest > request > **hawk@3.1.3:** This module moved to @hapi/hawk. Please make sure to switch over as this distribution is no longer supported and may contain bugs and critical security issues.
- warning strapi-plugin-users-permissions > purest > request > hawk > **hoek@2.16.3:** This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
- warning strapi-plugin-users-permissions > purest > request > hawk > **boom@2.10.1:** This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
- warning strapi-plugin-users-permissions > purest > request > hawk > boom > **hoek@2.16.3**: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
  warning strapi-plugin-users-permissions > purest > request > **node-uuid@1.4.8**: Use uuid module instead
- warning strapi-plugin-users-permissions > purest > request > hawk > **sntp@1.0.9:** This module moved to @hapi/sntp. Please make sure to switch over as this distribution is no longer supported and may contain bugs and critical security issues.
- warning strapi-plugin-users-permissions > purest > request > hawk > sntp > **hoek@2.16.3:** This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
- warning strapi-plugin-users-permissions > purest > request > hawk > **cryptiles@2.0.5**: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
- warning strapi-plugin-users-permissions > purest > request > hawk > cryptiles > **boom@2.10.1**: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
- warning strapi-plugin-email > strapi-provider-email-sendmail > sendmail > **mailcomposer@3.12.0:** This project is unmaintained
- warning strapi-plugin-email > strapi-provider-email-sendmail > sendmail > mailcomposer > **buildmail@3.10.0**: This project is unmaintained
  error eslint@6.4.0: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version "^8.10.0 || ^10.13.0 || >=11.10.1". Got "11.9.0"

**error Found incompatible module.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: slackanswer]

You are using the wrong node version, node 11 isn't supported as the error suggests